# scroll events: requestAnimationFrame VS requestIdleCallback VS passive event listeners

Tags: javascript, dom, requestanimationframe, requestidlecallback, passive-event-listeners

As we know, it's often advised to debounce scroll listeners so that UX is better when the user is scrolling.

However, I've often found [libraries](https://github.com/WPOTools/steady.js) and [articles](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/debounce-your-input-handlers) where influential people like Paul Lewis recommend using `requestAnimationFrame`. However as the web platform progress rapidly, it might be possible that some advice get deprecated over time.

The problem I see is there are very different use-cases for handling scroll events, like building a parallax website, or handling infinite scrolling and pagination.

I see 3 major tools that can make a difference in term of UX:

- [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)
- [requestIdleCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback)
- [Passive event listeners](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md)

So, I'd like to know, per usecase (I only have 2 but you can come up with other ones), what kind of tool should I use right now to have a very good scroll experience?

To be more precise, my main question would be more related to infinite scrolling views and pagination (which generally do not have to trigger visual animations, but we want a good scrolling experience), is it better to replace `requestAnimationFrame` with a combo of `requestIdleCallback` + passive scroll event handler ? I'm also wondering when it makes sense to use `requestIdleCallback` for calling an API or handling the API response to let the scroll perform better, or is it something that the browser may already handle for us?

Comment: I like this question, but i fear without some code snippets, most people are afraid to start an opinionated debate... do you have time to provide some examples?

Comment: @op can you provide an example snippet that demonstrates a scrolling feature like you want, so people can use that in an answer? I might consider putting a bounty on it then. Right now it's too broad.

Comment: @Tschallacka as explained above I'm not looking particularly for one usecase but for how to make the decisions on a per usecase basis. The most simplest and common usecase you can think of is probably some kind of infinite scrolling view like Instagram, Twitter or Facebook do

Comment: @SebastienLorber It makes your question incredibly broad, and browser all have different implementations and optimisations. If your question doesn't get narrowed down to specifics it might end up closed as too broad.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Although this question is a little bit older, I want to answer it because I often see scripts, where a lot of these techniques are misused.

In general all your asked tools (`rAF`, `rIC` and passive listeners) are great tools and won't vanish soon. But you have to know why to use them.

Before I start: In case you generate scroll synced/scroll linked effects like parallax effects/sticky elements, throttling using `rIC`, `setTimeout` doesn't make sense because you want to react immediately.

### `requestAnimationFrame`

`rAF` gives you the point inside the frame life cycle right before the browser wants to calculate the new style and layout of the document. This is why it is perfect to use for animations. First it won't be called more often or less often than the browser calculates layout  (right frequency). Second it is called right before the browser does calculate the layout (right timing). In fact using `rAF` for any layout changes (DOM or CSSOM changes) makes a lot of sense. `rAF` is synced with the [display refresh rate (vsync)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate) as any other layout rendering related stuff in the browser.

#### using `rAF` for throttle/debounce

The default example of Paul Lewis looks like this:

```
var scheduledAnimationFrame;
function readAndUpdatePage(){
  console.log('read and update');
  scheduledAnimationFrame = false;
}

function onScroll (evt) {

  // Store the scroll value for laterz.
  lastScrollY = window.scrollY;

  // Prevent multiple rAF callbacks.
  if (scheduledAnimationFrame){
    return;
  }

  scheduledAnimationFrame = true;
  requestAnimationFrame(readAndUpdatePage);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

This pattern is very often used/copied, although it makes little till no sense in practice. (And I'm asking myself why no developer sees this obvious problem.) In general, theoretically it makes a lot of sense to throttle everything to at least the `rAF`, because it doesn't make sense to request layout changes from the browser more often than the browser renders the layout.

However the `scroll` event is triggered every time the browser **renders**  a scroll position change. This means a `scroll` event is synchronized with the rendering of the page. Literally the same thing that `rAF` is giving you. This means it doesn't make any sense to throttle something by something, that is already throttled by the exact same thing per definition.

In practice you can check what I just said by adding a `console.log` and check how often this pattern "prevents multiple rAF callbacks" (answer is none, otherwise it would be a browser bug).

```
  // Prevent multiple rAF callbacks.
  if (scheduledAnimationFrame){
    console.log('prevented rAF callback');
    return;
  }
```

As you will see this code is never executed, it is simply dead code.

But there is a very similar pattern that make sense for a different reason. It looks like this:

```
//declare box, element, pos
function writeLayout(){
    element.classList.add('is-foo');
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=> {
    box = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    if(box.top > pos){
        requestAnimationFrame(writeLayout);
    }
});
```

With this pattern you can successfully reduce or even remove layout thrashing. The idea is simple: inside of your scroll listener you read layout and decide wether you need to modify the DOM and then you call the function that modifies the DOM using rAF. Why is this helpful? The `rAF` makes sure that you move your layout invalidation (at the end of the frame). This means any other code that is called inside the same frame works on a valid layout and can operate with super fast layout read methods.

This pattern is in fact so great, that I would suggest the following helper method (written in ES5):

```
/**
 * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/44779316
 *
 * @param {Function} fn Callback function
 * @param {Boolean|undefined} [throttle] Optionally throttle callback
 * @return {Function} Bound function
 *
 * @example
 * //generate rAFed function
 * jQuery.fn.addClassRaf = bindRaf(jQuery.fn.addClass);
 *
 * //use rAFed function
 * $('div').addClassRaf('is-stuck');
 */
function bindRaf(fn, throttle) {
  var isRunning;
  var that;
  var args;

  var run = function() {
    isRunning = false;
    fn.apply(that, args);
  };

  return function() {
    that = this;
    args = arguments;

    if (isRunning && throttle) {
      return;
    }

    isRunning = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
  };
}
```

### `requestIdleCallback`

Is from the API similar to `rAF` but gives something totally different. It gives you some idle periods inside of a frame. (Normally the point after the browser has calculated layout and done paint, but there is still some time left until the v-sync happens.)  Even if the page is laggy from the users view, there might be some frames, where the browser is idling. Although `rIC` can give you max. 50ms. Most of the time you only have between 0.5 and 10ms to fulfill your task. Due to the fact at which point in the frame life cycle `rIC` callbacks are called you should not alter the DOM (use `rAF` for this).

At the end it makes a lot of sense to throttle the `scroll` listener for lazyloading, infinite scrolling and such using `rIC`. For these kinds of user interfaces you can even throttle more and add a `setTimeout` in front of it. (so you do 100ms wait and then a `rIC`)

> Live examples for [debounce](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/57e719f873ed552e43c877c2c8f8deb0364d6c6e/lazysizes-umd.js#L216-L240) and [throttle](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/57e719f873ed552e43c877c2c8f8deb0364d6c6e/lazysizes-umd.js#L166-L213).)

Here is [also an article about `rAF`](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4), that includes two diagrams which might help to understand the different points inside of a "frame lifecycle".

### Passive event listener

Passive event listeners were invented to improve scroll performance. Modern browsers moved page scrolling (scroll rendering) from the main thread to the composition thread.  (see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/02/smoother-scrolling-in-firefox-46-with-apz/)

But there are events that produce scrolling, which can be prevented by script (which happens in the main thread and therefore can revert the performance improvement).

Which means as soon as one of these events listeners are bound, the browser has to wait for these listener to be executed before the browser can compute the scroll. These events are mainly `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`, `wheel` and in theory to some degree `keypress` and `keydown`. The `scroll` event itself is **not** one of these events. The `scroll` event has no default action, that can be prevented by script.

This means if you don't use `preventDefault` in your `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` and/or `wheel`, always use passive event listeners and you should be fine.

In case you use preventDefault, check wether you can substitute it with the CSS `touch-action` property or lower it at least in your DOM tree (for example no event delegation for these events). In case of `wheel` listeners you might be able to bind/unbind them on `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`.

In case of any other event: It does not make sense to use passive event listeners to improve performance. Most important to note: **The `scroll` event can't be canceled and therefore it *never* makes sense to use passive event listeners for `scroll`.**

In case of an infinite scrolling view you don't need `touchmove`, you only need `scroll`, so passive event listeners do not even apply.

### Resume

To answer your question

- for lazyloading, infinite view use a combination of `setTimeout` + `requestIdleCallback` for your event listeners and use `rAF` for any layout writes (DOM mutations).
- for instant effects still use `rAF` for any layout writes (DOM mutations).

Comment: Wow. Such a great answer. Maybe it should've been a blog post.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Not totally sure about `the scroll event is triggered every time the browser renders a scroll position change`: for me it's likely that the rAF callback gets always fired before the next scroll event, thus not producing the log

Comment: Also for things like a sticky header, or a "scrollTop button", for me it seems to make sense to use a passive event listener on the scroll event no? We won't prevent scrolling to happen and don't necessarily need 16ms feedback for these kind of features (unlike parallax)

Comment: @SebastienLorber: Don't understand your rAF/scroll event objection. As I described in my answer rAF is synced with the V-Sync and scroll rendering is also synced with the V-Sync. So yes, rAF is always called before the next scroll event and throtteling makes only sense, if something has a different frequency (slower) that the other thing. The fact that you don't see a console demonstrates how useless this pattern is.

Comment: @SebastienLorber: About passive event listener and `scroll` event. The `scroll` event is not `cancelable`, this means even if you call `preventDefault` it has no effect. The browser doesn't do anything different if you use the passive option.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know I thought the scroll change was the default behavior happening after the scroll event, but it makes sense to render first and emit scroll next so that we can receive new scroll position and do some maths...

Comment: I would say this pattern exists so often because it can be found on [MDN: scroll, Scroll optimization with window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll#Scroll_optimization_with_window.requestAnimationFrame) and MDN is normally seen a reliable source. So if your claim is correct. Then one should propose an amendment on the MDN page?

Comment: The MDN page does actually state that this optimization is 'often unnecessary' as rAF and Scroll fire at 'about the same rate'.

Comment: I'm debating with a colleague as to whether making an event handler passive effects how quickly it gets called (i.e. effects the handler's "priority"). I understand that it does not. Am I correct?

Comment: Beautifully explained answer. I couldn't find anything better than this on the internet. You are a god.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas You're stating that "[Paul Lewis' pattern] makes little till no sense in practice". Okay I understand that. But when I debug `isRunning` together with a scroll event, I noticed that its also never true.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas I'm wondering what I'm missing, you wrote: 
"This means it doesn't make any sense to throttle something by something, that is already throttled by the exact same thing per definition." 
-- about requestAnimationFrame on scroll.
And later in "Resume" you're saying:  "for instant effects still use rAF for any layout writes (DOM mutations)."

I'm guessing that by instant effects you mean scroll effects, like parallax. So could you clarify it for me, please?